# Errors viewing the scala html templates in Play

Tags: playframework, scala-ide, playframework-2.4

I am just getting started with Play framework, I hardly converted the play-java project to eclipse project and imported it into the Eclipse IDE as eclipse required some additional plugin, I tried downloading the Scala IDE which has play supportive plugins inbuilt and imported the project, it works.

But when I open the two default html files, index.scala.html and main.scala.html, the editor shows errors as shown below.

[image]

[image]

How to resolve these setup issues? I am using the latest Play framework Play 2.4.2 and my Scala IDE downloaded file name: scala-SDK-4.1.0-vfinal-2.11-win32.win32.x86_64

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem, there is an [issue](https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-ide-play2/issues/249) on GitHub for this that is still open.

Linked to from this issue is a [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-ide-user/WFNoQ6GNw1k) on `scala-ide-user` group with several possible solutions offered in the form of replacement `.jar`'s.

I'd keep an eye on those two links for when this is fixed.